# $scope.watch() in a link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I finally have an object and have some of its data dynamically created.  But I now want to use a button to increment through my data set and I cant get this to work. I thought I needed to use the scope.watch but after wrapping my elem.append in the watch function it still doesn't catch when I click the button and increment through my array.

this is my first time playing with templates and directives and it is kicking my butt.

All help is greatly appreciated.

app.js

```
angular.module("App", [])
    .controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.count=0;
        $scope.bpmSong=[{
                "AlbumName":"Unknown Album",
                "ArtistName":"Angel City",
                "SongName":"Love Me Right Feat. Laura McAllen[Rezonance Q Remix]",
                "$id":"4453334",
                "$priority":null
            },
                {
                    "AlbumName":"Immersion",
                    "ArtistName":"Pendulum",
                    "SongName":"The Island - Part 1 - Dawn",
                    "$id":"26593443",
                    "$priority":null
                },
                {
                    "AlbumName":"Someone to Love Me",
                    "ArtistName":"Jomanda",
                    "SongName":"Got a Love for You",
                    "$id":"29376555",
                    "$priority":null
                },
                {
                    "AlbumName":"Avicii - Essential Mix (2010-12-11)",
                    "ArtistName":"Avicii",
                    "SongName":"Penguin",
                    "$id":"29533653",
                    "$priority":null
                },
                {
                    "AlbumName":"MOS Addicted To Bass 2011",
                    "ArtistName":"Eric Prydz",
                    "SongName":"Niton (The Reason)",
                    "$id":"30154682",
                    "$priority":null
                }]
    })
    .directive('flashWidget', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                song: '='
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.numb = 0;
                $scope.click = function () {
                    $scope.numb++
                }
            },
            template: '<button ng-click="click()">Click me</button> Clicked {{numb}} times',
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                scope.$watch(scope.song[scope.numb].$id, function(){
                    elem.append('<object width="250" height="40">'+
                        '<embed src="http://grooveshark.com/songWidget.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="250" height="40" flashvars="hostname=cowbell.grooveshark.com&songIDs=' +
                        scope.song[scope.numb].$id +
                        '&style=metal&p=0" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="window"></embed>'+
                        '</object>'
                    );
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>This is from the Controller and Directive</h2>
        <flash-widget song="bpmSong"></flash-widget>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="dist/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/tester.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
scope.$watch(scope.song[scope.numb].$id, function() {
```

Will be the same as:

```
scope.$watch('4453334', function() {
```

What you need is:

```
scope.$watch(function () { return scope.song[scope.numb].$id; }, function() {
```

Note that you need to make sure that `scope.numb` is not greater than the length of `scope.song` (in `$scope.click` for example, and/or that `scope.song[song.numb]` is not `undefined` in the `scope.$watch` watchExpression.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/0wcJFTvBZxcBGKcRBWOc?p=preview

Comment: perfect answer man thanks, if I wanted to instead of adding an additional elem and just change/refresh the current flash player how would I do that?

Comment: You're welcome :) I can show you an example of that in an hour or two.